# Android fullscreen UI with scretched center

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

Is it possible to make Relative or Linear layout on android with fixed header 20 dp, fixed footer 15 dp, and center should be stretched to all screen height -35dp? 
Should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use many layouts for this s.a. RelativeLayout, LinearLayout or ConstraintLayout. I'd recommend RelativeLayout, inside which you put Views for header and footer and set their heights fixed. Here is an example of how you can do this in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_top"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_top"
        android:layout_above="@id/tv_bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is how it will look on a device:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Serj! Excellent solution!